# fits save multiple python

Tags: python

i want to make an operation with fits an save them with specific name.
my code sofar:

```
    for root, dirs, files in sorted(os.walk("path")):
        for i in range(len(files)):
            if files[i].endswith('ending.fits'):
                image1=fits.getdata('path of image1')
                imageX=fits.getdata(os.path.join(root, files[i]))
                image= 1- imageX/image1

                name= os.path.join(root, files[i]).split('/')[-4:-1]
                #i want these 4 splits as name of the new files

                hdu = fits.PrimaryHDU(image)
                hdulist = fits.HDUList([hdu])
                hdulist.writeto('/net/home/folder/'+ name, overwrite=True)
```

when i start this, it gives me 
cannot concatenate 'str' and 'list' objects
and when i type this:

```
      hdulist.writeto('/net/home/folder/file.fits, overwrite=True)
```

it overwrite one file about 20times (i have about 20 images)

please help

Comment: You have a basic coding error.  I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do with `name= os.path.join(root, files[i]).split('/')[-4:-1]` but `.split('/')` returns a `list` object so now `name` is a `list`.  Later you try to concatenate it with a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line

```
name= os.path.join(root, files[i]).split('/')[-4:-1]
```

to this:

```
name= '/'.join(os.path.join(root, files[i]).split('/')[-4:-1])
```